# Appium + Android Camera : How to automate android camera scenarios using Appium? Any work around?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, mobile-automation, test-strategy

I'm trying to automate an `Android test` on a `real device` using `Appium` in which I have an application.

In order to complete a registration, the application will ask the user to take a Selfie, so when the user clicks this button the device camera opens up.

the only thing, that is missing, is that I can't find a way how to click on the button to take a photo.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: How to write script for camera functionality for android devices. The script will run in any mobile devices not in any specific. The UI and functionality of every devices is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ASR7, No - I would like to correct below things

1. We can not automate android mobile app automation using Selenium. Selenium is use to automate web/browser automation
2. Facility in order to automate Android mobile app test case, one may use Appium

   3.1  BTW & Answer to your Q - It doesn't allow to identify elements from another android app.

   3.2 As one will not able to identify element of another app[2nd app or app which you might have opened from 1st your app] you can not make your script to click to take a selfie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA);`

You can find the documentation and other key events codes at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: can you expand your answer?  Why is that a good solution?

Comment: What does this add to the accepted answer?

Comment: It contradicts the accepted answer. I looked into the documentation and I think using the actual constant instead of the magic number makes it more clear. I don't know if it works, but it's a promising lead.